# Qt implementing simple syntax highlighting

Tags: c++, qt, syntax, ide, syntax-highlighting

I'm currently working on a php ide.
I want to implement syntax highlighting.
I have already seen [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) but i don't understand it's code.
It doesn't seem right to use code that i don't understand.
What i have change something but i won't be able to?

Can somebody point me in the right direction?
If that is really hard to achieve in qt.
Is there any better framework for IDE development?

Thank you!
P.S Does it matter if i use qt-4?

Comment: I've used the `QSyntaxHighlighter` before, it's pretty simple but also limited I'd say. I don't think it should be used for highly dynamic and possibly large text like source code, because you have to evaluate the whole text every time the user changes something. That's at least how I understand it. You just provide some RegEx's and those are used so color the matching strings, it's good enough for simple highlighting, but in your case I'd look into teh source code of QtCreator itself, how they handle code highlighting maybe?

Comment: Have you looked at the [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html)?

Comment: @xander I think they use `QSyntaxHighlighter`. You do not have to use regular expressions, you can use whatever logic you want. Qt format in chunks of blocks, i.e. paragraphs, not the whole text at once. The core of the highlighter is [`highlightBlock`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#highlightBlock), in which you should format the specified block.

Comment: Yes i have looked at example but it is coded in qt-5.

Comment: You can use [syntax-highlighting](https://inqlude.org/libraries/syntax-highlighting.html) library

Comment: @64humans I don't think there is much differnce with Qt4 and 5 in that example!? No new connection style or anything, or what is not working in Qt4 (that's pretty old to be honest I can't remember the differences).

Comment: @xander I tried implementing it and there is no include RegularExpressionMatch

Comment: @64humans oh yeah you might have to use [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) instead of QRegularExpression, just look at the doc.

Comment: @xander Thanks i will look into it then!

Comment: Also take a look at [QScintilla](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/intro).